# ASMX (web service) is not working in VB.NET for Mexican characters input

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I am not able to pass the Mexican char through ASMX (web service), I tried with adding some logic's  in the constructor to accept the Mexican char it is not working ..

Here is the code

```
Public Class VNSoap
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService : Implements IXXXXX
Public Sub New()
        HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm passing the char as 'Paul Pogbà' and getting the output as Paul Pogb??

The thing is my char is converted to ?? Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed ..While passing the request from PostMan ,I changad the contentType to 
"text/xml; charset=UTF-8" .